# How does the core framework of React Native get deployed to a device to be used by an app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I've watched quite a few React Native architecture and React Native under the hood guides, and read some articles, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this question:

How does the core framework of React Native get deployed to a device to be used by an app?

I'm specifically talking about the code that Facebook wrote to translate back and forth between JS and native (the bridge) and all the other core framework infrastructure used to make React Native work.

I assume that this code either already resides on the device (a phone for example), kind of like how the .NET CLR or Java SDK's are installed on a computer.

Either that or the core framework is bundled with every React Native app that is created and deployed with the app package.

If the former, then how does this initially get on the device (downloaded automatically to the device as a dependency when the app is installed/run for first time)?

If the latter, then does this bloat the device with unnecessary redundant code if the device has more that one React Native app installed (assuming same version of the core framework)?

Comment: Well i don't know what you've watched, but you deploy everything in your `.apk` and your `.ipa` both the core (obviously) and your js bundle.

Comment: React Native bundles in natively for each individual project. Imagine you've got an app running React Native 0.46, and one running a legacy version. The legacy app will not be able to use the newer framework version. In XCode and in the Libraries directory, you can see `React.xcodeproj`. Similarly, in `app/build.gradle` there is a `compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"` for Android. Let me know if this doesn't answer your question. Once you generate an `.apk` and/or `.ipa` these native modules get bundled into your app.

Comment: Thank you both, that explains it.